# Resume from suspension ask password to read smart data

Tags: release-juno

Every time I resume from suspension this window shows up:

[image]

xprop shows `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "io.elementary.pantheon-agent-polkit", "Io.elementary.pantheon-agent-polkit"`

Why this is appearing? How can I disable it?

I'm using Elementary Juno beta.

Comment: Hi, I had the same pop-up with Samsung Evo 850 250GB in Loki, so it's something persistent. :/